# How to set charset to UTF8 for text files with gsutil when uploading to Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build, gsutil

We have a (public) Google Cloud Storage bucket that hosts a simple website, meaning both HTML and images.

Our build process uses Google Cloud Build, however the question is not tied to using Cloud Build, but specifically regarding on how to use `gsutil` properly.

This is our current `gsutil` task:

```
# Upload it to the bucket
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  dir: "public/"
  args: [
    "-m", # run the rsync command in parallel
    "-h", "Cache-Control: public, max-age=0", # Custom cache control header
    "cp", # copy command
    "-r", # recursively
    ".", # source folder
    "gs://mybucket/" # the target bucket and folder
  ]
```

As you can see, this copies everything in the local `public/` folder to the bucket and applies the `Cache-Control` header on all objects.

According to this:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata

You can specify the content type with

```
-h "Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

However, this makes all objects (not only .html files, but also images, etc) to get the content type `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

(I have even tried `-h "Content-Type:; charset=utf-8"` but then `gsutil` fails saying its an invalid content type value).

Is there a way to tell `gsutil` to apply `charset=utf-8` on all objects, without actually overwriting the main content type?

Comment: Because the charset belong to the Content-type, you can't do that. If you specific the Content type, you have to fully define it, no partial update is possible

Comment: So I basically need a new "cp" command for each (text) file type, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct